# No module named azure.storage.blob - Azure Linux VM (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, azure

I have created a Linux VM (ubuntu 18.04) in Azure .Installed Python3.6 on that using sudo apt install python3.7. Python programs are running fine. Now tried to install azure-storage-blob. could not find any apt-get package. I tried with pip3 - first installed pip3 and then `sudo pip3 install azure-storage-blob`. It's installed successfully. Now tried to run the folllowing simple code

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

try:
    print("Azure Blob storage v12 - Python quickstart sample")
    # Quick start code goes here
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

Getting Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basicblob1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
ImportError: No module named azure.storage.blob
```

Comment: By default Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM image in Azure installs two version of python side by side . python 2.7 and 3.6.So there might be a problem of visibility of module from interpreter .So one needs to target python 3.6 for package installation .
sudo python3.6 -m pip install azure-storage-blob .Or Virtual Environment can be created to install all the project related artifacts alongwith packages required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the python script as **python3 basicblob1.py**, if not you can try

As in some of the ubuntu machines python 3 is linked to python3 and python 2 is linked to python.

Answer (score 0):

I remove all azure configuration from python3.10, a file and a directoy, then a reinstall the azure-storage-blob that works for me